# gnu make multiple targets one object each

Tags: gnu-make

I have an old project for which I'm trying to create a multiple binaries, one for each object in the directory.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to deal with multiple targets in this manner.  The following works, but it seems to me I should be able to have one rule to link them all, so to speak,

```
 # compile objects, no problem
 %.o: %.c
     $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

 bin: bin.o
     $(CC) -o $@ $< ../lib/libfoo.a -lm $(ARCH)

 bar: bar.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $< ../lib/libfoo.a -lm $(ARCH)
```

One approach that I did get to work is to strip off the suffix from the target name like this, and compile and link in one step, but it feels a little hackish,

```
 %.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< ../lib/libfoo.a -lm -o $(*F)
```

Disclaimer: I despise make

UPDATE 1: this is what I ended up with

```
 EXECS = bin bar ...

 all: $(EXECS)

 %: %.c
      @echo "Building $@ from $<"
      $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@.o
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $@.o ../lib/libfoo.a -lm -o $@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is to have something like this at the top of your Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all: bin bar
```

Thus `make all` will make `bin` and `bar`, and by putting it at the top it's the default target for `make` without arguments. The `.PHONY:` documents this as a "metatarget", but also instructs Make to run it even if there happens to be a file called `all` with a fresh datestamp.

```
%: %.o
     $(CC) -o $@ $< ../lib/libfoo.a -lm $(ARCH)
```

This tells Make how to make them both.

Comment: The second rule helped me get something closer to what I wanted, not sure why but when I used your example 'make all' was defaulting some some implicit rule for each of the binaries in the list (bin bar ...).